# Android square root calculation error

Tags: java, android, square-root

I wanted to make a Java app that calculates the square root using the Heron algorithm. But when I enter 9 it prints 2.777777910232544 to the screen.
When I enter 1 it prints 1. Now I do not know if I wrote the wrong code or I don't know something about floats in Java.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

float length1;
float width1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mainOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainOutput);
    final EditText mainInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainInput);
    final Button wurzel2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wurzel2);

    assert wurzel2 != null;
    wurzel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                float inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(mainInput.getText().toString());
                length1 = 1;
                width1 = inputNumber / length1;
                float length2 = (length1 + width1) / 2;
                float width2 = inputNumber / length2;
                length1 = length2;
                width1 = width2;
            }
            double wurzel = length1 / width1;
            mainOutput.setText(String.valueOf(wurzel));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Why not using the [sqrt() function](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double))?

Comment: Well I basically want to write the sqrt() function myself.

Comment: Why? It would be surely less performant than the optimized one already present in the Math library.

Comment: I have to make it as homework for school. And we are supposed to write it using this algorithm. I know that it would be much easier to just use the sqrt() function. I already wrote it in PHP and it worked but in Java I have no idea what i did wrong.

Comment: It seems an approximation error to me. Try Rounding the result to say 3 decimals.

Comment: `Android Studio calculation` ??? This has nothing to do with Android Stdio. Your Android app does the calculation. And it is your code.

Comment: It looks like a bad result. Maybe you should use double instread of float. Or iterate more.

Comment: ???? Your 20 times for loop makes no sense. You do twenty times the same. With the same value for the variables.

Comment: Sorry guys, I will  just rewrite the whole code and see if I am missing something. Sorry for stealing your time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a non-Android Java implementation of Heron's algorithm derived from the formula for the algorithm displayed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float x = 9;
        System.out.println(heron(x));
    }

    static float heron(float s) {
        float x = (float) 1.0; // initial approximation of result
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            float sDivX = s / x;
            x = (x + sDivX) / 2;
            // remove this line in production, this is just to watch progress
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(x));
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Your code had length1=1 (your length1 is equivalent to my x) inside the loop, so
it made no progress from iteration to iteration.

`x = s/(float)2` might be a better initial estimate than 1, especially for larger values. 20 iterations is probably overkill for smallish values of the input value.